# ArcGIS JavaScript 3.3 add ArcGIS REST API Queried Feature Layer URL as Layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query, arcgis-rest-api, spatial-query

Using the Query Generator on an ArcGIS REST Feature Layer, I generated a [URL](https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=%7Bxmin%3A%20-104%2C%20ymin%3A%2035.6%2C%20xmax%3A%20-94.32%2C%20ymax%3A%2041%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=html) that filters the data by a geometry extent ({xmin: -104, ymin: 35.6, xmax: -94.32, ymax: 41}) 
[image]

This returns Current River Conditions from 417 Gauge Stations from the [NWS Observations Rest Service](https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations).

I want to take this queried layer and add it as a layer in an ArcGIS JavaScript 3.30 Application I am building. I was previously able to add the entire layer (no extent query) as a Feature Layer like so:

```
#--------------Flood Stages-------------
/*
1) Current Flood Stage Points for Texas with custom symbology and attribute info
*/
var currentFloodStg = new FeatureLayer("https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0", {
    copyright: "NOAA/NWS/NWC"
});
map.addLayer(currentFloodStg);
```

[image]
However it is a requirement that I filter down the number of points to a restricted area, I am aware that I can potentially query this Feature layer as a [Graphics Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/javascript/query-a-feature-layer/), however considering I have the queried ArcGIS REST API URL, is there a way to add this as an interactive layer on the map through the URL produced by the Query Generator without needing to perform the queries using JavaScript?

I suppose I could adjust that URL to produce a GeoJSON/KMZ/JSON output, and then map that file type in accordance to how the [ArcGIS JavaScript 3.30 API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/) documentation dictates that particular data structure can be mapped as its own layer. If there is a simpler method I am all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better solution both for performance and simplicity might be to use the FeatureLayer with a definitionExpression. This is possible since your data is point data and the latitude and longitude information is available as specific attribute fields (not just in the geometry).

`latitude between 35.6 and 41 AND longitude between -104 and -94.32`

[REST example](https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0/query?where=latitude%20between%2035.6%20and%2041%20AND%20longitude%20between%20-104%20and%20-94.32&outFields=latitude%2C%20longitude&returnGeometry=true&f=html)

Using JSAPI:

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(
  "https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0",
  {
    definitionExpression: "latitude between 35.6 and 41 AND longitude between -104 and -94.32"
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi Bjorn, thanks for the reply- have any reference on where I could toss in the reference expression? Thanks!

Comment: @Just_African_Developer - see JAPI reference - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer1
I also updated my answer to include a code snippet for it.

Comment: Nice and lightweight, thanks for the answer! Can't believe I skipped over something so efficient.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This works, however Bjorn pointed me in the right direction with his answer using definitionExpressions, it is significantly more lightweight and seemingly better on performance!

So looking at my options more, I see that the easiest way for me would be to change to ArcGIS Javscript 4.13 and edit the URL to return a Geojson and map it using the [GeoJSONLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-geojson/index.html) Method:

```
var geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
  url: url,
  copyright: "NOAA/NWS/NWC",
  popupTemplate: template
});
```

To handle this in ArcGIS Javascript 3.3

- I would need to adjust the URL to return a JSON file.
- Then using the Javscript API create a new [Feature Collection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_featureCollection.html)
- Then create new Layer Definition to match the JSON structure returned by the URL and
  define the attributes I care about.
- I can then map that featureCollection as a new FeatureLayer (similar to [this Example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_featureCollection.html) from the ArcGIS Javascript 3.3 documentation).